# List comprehension: avoid the warning 'Cannot access member "get" for type "list[Unknown]"'. How to?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pylance

I'm trying to clean up a tiny bit my python code and remove as many as Pylance warnings (albeit the code has been tested and it works).
Particularly, I'm struggling with the following one.

[image]

I've my `ctr` variable holding a list, and each `item` contains a set made by a numerical index and a dictionary.

```
ctr = sorted(ctr_calc.find_ctr().items())
vals = [(r, round(v.get('ctr'), 2)) for r, v in ctr[1:-1]]
```

The error I get is `Cannot access member "get" for type "list[Unknown]"`. Per se the error is already not correct, as v once accessed is a dictionary and not anymore a list.

Is there anyway to get rid of this warning (other than adding # ignore)?

Comment: What is the type hint for the return value of `ctr_calc.find_ctr()`?

Comment: It's a defaultdict class the one I return (of list type)

Comment: Are you sure ctr is a list of sets? I suspect it's either a list of lists or maybe a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the way you're accessing *ctr* I suspect that it's either a list of lists or a list of tuples.

If you provide a type hint for *ctr* Pylance will know what your code is dealing with and the warning will go away.

```
ctr: list[tuple[int, dict]] = sorted(ctr_calc.find_ctr().items())
```

...or...

```
ctr: list[list[int, dict]] = sorted(ctr_calc.find_ctr().items())
```

Comment: Sorry, haven't forgotten to test .. it's simply that I had some "issues" to solve first. A question in the meantime. Would be the above working also to declare the variables in a custom defined class e.g. `self.something: list(Type("MyClass")) = None` ... because whilst I can get it done by Pylance still complains that `Call expression not allowed in type expression`. I got rid of it with a `# type: ignore` after, but my main goal was to have a working code without tricks. So am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: @AndreaMoro I suggest you raise another question with full details of your latest coding attempt and a description of the issues you're [still] seeing